# touchesBegan don't callback?

Tags: iphone

I have one scrollView and there is ImageView in it but when i click on UIImageView the touchesBegan doesn't called? Please give me any idea why it happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIImageView turns off the `userInteractionEnabled` flag by default. Turn it on.

Comment: I have already done it. I checked the UserIntractionEnabled and Multitouch also.

Comment: Is it nested in a parent view that has userInteractionEnabled off? Also double-check that your touchesBegan method is named correctly and implemented on the correct object.